# Web scraper giving random values

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, data-science, data-science-experience

At work I was tasked with doing a market analysis of bricks. I chose some competitors and made web scrapers to collect their prices.
It works for most brick types, however on some it will change the value or say there's isn't a match when there is.

The issues are only with the Prices_Building. The rest of the code works well, weirdly, if I use the Prices_Building code to search for just one name, it'll get it right.

Here is an image of [Output spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydDMH.png)

the ones in green are correct values on the website, the ones in red are incorrect with the correct value in {} if it exists.

Here is my code:

```
sheet = client.open("Bricks Compare Prices").get_worksheet(0)



Prices_Amari = []
Prices_Wholesale = []
Prices_Building = []
Names = []
Prices_Amari = []
#List of bricks to compare
lis = [ (list of names boiled down to NAME pack of SIZE

]

Prices_Building = []
Namez = []
for name in lis: # for every name in the list
    target = name.rpartition("Pack")[0] #get the essential name 
    pack_size = re.search(pattern = '[0-9]+', string=name).group() #get the pack size
    res = requests.get("https://eucs13.ksearchnet.com/cloud-search/n-search/search?ticket=klevu-15598202362809967&term={}&paginationStartsFrom=0&sortPrice=false&ipAddress=undefined&analyticsApiKey=klevu-15598202362809967&showOutOfStockProducts=true&klevuFetchPopularTerms=false&klevu_priceInterval=500&fetchMinMaxPrice=true&klevu_multiSelectFilters=true&noOfResults=1&klevuSort=rel&enableFilters=true&layoutVersion=1.0&autoComplete=false&autoCompleteFilters=&filterResults=&visibility=search&category=KLEVU_PRODUCT&klevu_filterLimit=50&sv=2316&lsqt=&responseType=json&klevu_loginCustomerGroup=".format(name))
    results = json.loads(res.text)['result'] #go to this site, search for the brick 

for i in results: #for every result, check that the name and pack size is in the title, or sau there's no match
    if target in i['name'] and pack_size in i['name']:
        Prices_Building.append(i['salePrice'])
        Namez.append(i['name'])
    else:
        Prices_Building.append("No match in Building Supplies Online" + name)
        Namez.append(i['name'])
```

#repeat for other website
for Name in lis:

```
def get_url_Amaari(search_term):
    build = 'https://ammaaristones.co.uk/?s={}&post_type=product'
    url = build.format(search_term)
    return url
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
result_Ammaristones = requests.get(get_url_Amaari(Name), headers=headers)
try:
    soupAmm = BeautifulSoup(result_Ammaristones.text, 'lxml')
    Par = soupAmm.find('div', class_='box-text box-text-products')
    PriceAmm = re.findall("[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?",Par.find('bdi').text)[0]
    Prices_Amari.append(PriceAmm)

except:
    PriceAmm = "no match in Ammari Stones for:" + Name
    Prices_Amari.append(PriceAmm)
    pass
```

#repeat for other website
for Name in lis:

```
try:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    def get_url_Wholesale(search_term):
        build = 'https://brickwholesale.co.uk/?s={}&post_type=product&dgwt_wcas=1'
        url = build.format(search_term)
        return url
    result_Wholesale = requests.get(get_url_Wholesale(Name), headers=headers)


    soupWhole = BeautifulSoup(result_Wholesale.text, 'html.parser')
    Pparent = soupWhole.find_all('span', class_='woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol')
    Whole = (float(re.findall("[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?",soupWhole.find('bdi').text.strip())[0]))*1.2+96
    PriceWhole = math.floor(Whole)
    if PriceWhole == 96:
        PriceWhole = "No Match in Wholesale Bricks for: " + Name
    
    Prices_Wholesale.append(PriceWhole)
    
except:
    PriceWhole = "no match in wholesale Bricks Stones for:" + Name
```

#print to google sheet one row at a time, matching up the prices for comparison

```
for j in range(len(lis)):
    time.sleep(1)
    row =[lis[j],Prices_Amari[j], Prices_Building[j], Prices_Wholesale[j]]
    sheet.append_row(row)
```

Comment: I think you should make your 'except:' code __always__ print the exception because it's possible (likely?) that your suppressing exceptions that are cauding problems with youtr results. Are the red ones always wrong? What does the data received for them look like?

Comment: It seems the error is, the list I'm putting in is larger than the list it's giving back. It has the error index out of range. it seems only the Prices_building list is one short, and that one short is pushing everything up. If you see the red errors, they're meant to be the values above them.

It's always the same bricks that are the problem, and it'll get some data like 
you'd search " Abbey Red Multi Pack of 452" and it'll return for Price_buildings something like "Abbey Blend pack of 452: 477" but as Abbey Red Multi isn't in Abbey blend red, it'll append "No match" not the price.

Comment: print(len(lis),len(Prices_Amari),len(Prices_Building),len(Prices_Wholesale)) returns the following: 47 47 46 47, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `except:` where you don't print or report the exception is very dangerous because you're completely hiding every exception that could happen. You should as an absolute minimum print the exception, or to do it properly use a specific except for the exceptions you expect could happen and are willing to suppress but let the others raise themselves and stop your code so you know something unusual has happened.

Comment: The code causing the error has no exceptions(only prices_building block of code), I'll add the specific exceptions. Great idea, the other exceptions are because the scraper found nothing and so i want it to show as no match found.